# Configure Intellij IDEA to default to Cucumber Java when Ruby plugin is enabled

Tags: java, ruby, intellij-idea, cucumber, intellij-plugin

I have configured a **Cucumber** project using **Cucumber Java** in **Intellij IDEA**.
I am able to execute the scenarios within a feature file using Cucumber Java (by executing the entire feature file and selecting Cucumber Java), but I am not able to execute a separate scenario due to Ruby plugin.
Specifically, when I click to run a specific scenario, Intellij IDEA defaults the execution to **Cucumber** (with **Ruby**) instead of **Cucumber Java**.

I need the **Ruby** plugin, since I am using the same IDE for another project which needs the Ruby support but I don't need the Cucumber support for it.

How can I disable **Cucumber (Ruby)** and default the scenario execution to **Cucumber Java**?

**Update**: IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.1 (Ultimate Edition)

Comment: There's a corresponding issue on the tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-28750 Could you please check which options there're if you invoke the context menu instead?

Comment: Thank you @Olivia , it really seems to be a regression bug in IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.1 version.

Comment: After some time, when I try to run the full feature file I am not already getting the context menu and the Cucumber (Ruby) is invoked without even offering the option of running the feature file with Cucumber Java. So it is the same behavior as when trying to run a single scenario. 

Is there a way to disable Cucumber (Ruby) when the Ruby plugin is enabled?

Comment: The current approach that I took in order to solve the given issue is to install yet another plugin -- [Cucumber +](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16289-cucumber-).

Answer (score 0):

I got opposite issue with rubby project and Idea runs features as cucumber java. Temp solution for me was dissable cucumber java plugin